# Simple javascript page button navigationg

Tags: javascript, html, navigation

Not sure why this isn't working.http://jsfiddle.net/PXrzh/

```
<button onclick="go()" >go</button>
```

js

```
function go() {
   window.location.href = "Confirmation.html";
}
```

Comment: Works fine if you place the function in the head: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/PXrzh/1/

Comment: What if I was trying to reference this in another js file? I can't get it to work, was hoping there was a syntax mishap. `go = function() {
  window.location.href = "Confirmation.html";
}` doesnt work in my js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function go() {
            window.location.href = "Confirmation.html";
        }
    </script>
    <body>
        <button onclick="go()" >go</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Found no issues...

UPDATE

index.js

```
function go() {
    window.location.href = "Confirmation.html";
}
```

index.html

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
    <body>
        <button onclick="go()" >go</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

still no issues...

Comment: Ok, well it must be something else causing the problem. Not sure why, should still work even dumbed down to this level.